# What is wrong with my shuffling program?

Tags: javascript, shuffle

I wrote a shuffling program below and ran it through ["Will It Shuffle?"](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/compare.html). The results appear to show that it's working in the console; it's shuffling the array. But the website shows me an all red box, making me think something is wrong with my code, but I don't see it.

```
function shuffle (array) {
    var arr = [],
        length = array.length,
        el;

    while (length > 0) {
      var randomEl = Math.floor(Math.random() * (length - 0) - 0);
      if (length > 1) {
        el = array.splice(randomEl,1);
      } else {
        el = array.splice(0,1);
      }
        arr.push(el[0]);
        length -= 1;
    }

  return arr;
}
```

Comment: Did you test it in the console? did you run theirs? You return, they do not. They alter the array, you do not

Comment: From a test on an array from 1 to 10, it looks random enough that I think the issue lies in the Will It Shuffle site.

Comment: @epascarello, Yes, many times. Someone had said my last sorting code wasn't good and sent me that website. I wrote this one, tested it on that website, and the cells are completely red, even though the console shows me it's shuffling the array fine. Sorry, new to JS.

Comment: Why do you check `length > 1`? If it's 1, then `randomEl` will be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That page ignores the returned value of the function, because it expects an [in-place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm) sort.

If you add this at the end of your code, it works as expected:

```
array.push(...arr);
```

You can also do it in-place directly:

```
function shuffle (array) {
  var length = array.length;
  while (length) {
    var randomEl = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
    var el = array.splice(randomEl, 1);
    array.push(el[0]);
    --length;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Oriol. I'm still learning JS, so I'm not familiar with pushing "...arr". Could you explain why that works with the ellipses too?

Comment: @BeerBeard That's the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator). For example, if you have `arr = [1,2,3]`, then `array.push(...arr)` behaves like `array.push(1,2,3)`. That is, it pushes all elements of `arr` to `array`.

Comment: I found the other answers helpful, but I appreciate your answer a lot, especially the sources you provided on spread operator, in-place sort, and another variation of my code performing in-place. Good learning and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

They alter the array, you do not alter the array.

You need to alter the original array, not return a new array.

```
function shuffle (array) {
    var arr = [],
        length = array.length,
        el;

    while (length > 0) {
      var randomEl = Math.floor(Math.random() * (length - 0) - 0);
      if (length > 1) {
        el = array.splice(randomEl,1);
      } else {
        el = array.splice(0,1);
      }
        arr.push(el[0]);
        length -= 1;
    }

  //replace array with the new items 
  //it is like using concat, but does not produce a new array, 
  //just appends it to the original which has zero items in it.
  Array.prototype.push.apply(array, arr);  



}
```

Comment: I know what you mean, but this answer is not very clear. [BTW no downvote from me :)] Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is creating a new array with the elements of the original shuffled around.

However, if you go back and look at the array that you passed in, you'll notice it has not been shuffled, but rather emptied. Apparently, this is not what "Will it Shuffle?" asks you to do.

splice() and push() both always mutate the array you call those methods on.

To answer your question about .push(...arr), an elipses in javascript is a feature that arrived with the latest version, EcmaScript 2015. It is the "spread operator".

When you call a function with a "spread" array, it's like calling the function with the contents of the array as separate arguments. For instance,

```
array.push(...[1,2,3])
```

is the same as calling

```
array.push(1,2,3)
```

push() can add an arbitrary number of comma-separated arguments to an array. So, after emptying the array argument with your looped splices, you could push the contents of the newly-created arr to the empty array using the spread operator.